# Cannot access the boot manager

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, boot-manager

I had installed a `MSI G41m-P33 combo` Motherboard recently and since then, I have not been able to access the boot manager by pressing `F12`. It does not even show the keys to press during the PC start up.
 I need to reinstall Windows 7 using a bootable USB.
Using a DVD works fine, but I still want to use the bootable USB.

Comment: The board you mention uses DEL as the key to access the BIOS.  Will that allow you to set boot order? Is there even a boot manager for that board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go into the BIOS by using the <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and change the boot  priority option there.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, by pressing Del key. Bot how did you know that?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Maybe he spent a few minutes and actually read [the manual](http://www.msi.com/support/mb/G41M-P33-Combo.html#down-manual)? ;)